# Rogue Order Hall Quest: Throwing SI:7 Off the Trail

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Having trouble with the Throwing SI:7 Off The Trail quest. I've completed all but the Suramar objectives and after several weeks of checking in, it's not loading to the Quest Board. Is there a prerequisite I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no further prerequisite if you're already on that quest. If there would be one you wouldn't have been able to pick it up in the first place.

---

There are two things that I can think of.

If you're in the middle of an artifact quest for any weapon (current or off-spec) complete it first. I've seen the quest missions not showing up for some reason while working on an artifact quest. This happened on my rogue as well as on two of my shamans.

Another thing is to send your followers on other missions. It has been reported on the official forums and on WoWHead that those missions tend to pop up after sending your followers away to do another mission. Just pick missions with a short duration so you don't lose much time.

---

If both solutions don't help open a GM ticket to request help. This would at least save the time to abort the quest and start over.

Or if you just can't wait any longer...
Abandon the quest and pick it up again. Start over and try again.

Comment: For any unlucky soul going through the same thing, here's what I've done so far:

1. Dropped the quest and picked it back up with the same result
2. Completed several other job board quests, checking back in daily for a few weeks
3. Ensured artifact questlines and world quest questlines were completed

Then I opened a GM ticket. The first response was generic, basically asking me to check WoWHead. I responded and got an actual human response suggesting I report it as a bug. I've submitted the bug report, and am now awaiting a reply.

Comment: @LearnWorkLearn  Wow... that was some unfriendly GM response tbh. Create another ticket and try again. You will never ever get a response from bug reports. They're just being listed somewhere deep in a basement to eventually get picked up sometime in the future.